# template does not exit error, my template stored in project root directory name template

Tags: django

Template-loader postmortem

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: Using loader
>   django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   C:\Users\manu\Desktop\ecom\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html
>   (File does not exist)
>   C:\Users\manu\Desktop\ecom\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html
>   (File does not exist)
>
> C:\Users\manu\Desktop\ecom\liquer\liquer\views.py in index
>                   return render_to_response('index.html',RequestContext(request))

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have `TEMPLATE_DIRS` variable set in settings file

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/path/to/templates/folder',
)
```

and put your all templates in it(for e.g `index.html`)